# Rebus: a very specific remix of a past song hit

Tags: rebus, music

*3 words*

[image] [image] [image] [image]

---

*3 words*

[image] [image] [image]

---

*1 word*

[image]

---

Exact youtube title:

> 3 words + " - " + 3 words + " (" + one word + ") "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> [Gabe the Dog - What is Dog (Haddaway)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtA_WnBP_Co)

Explanation:

> [Gabe Newell](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabe_Newell) + th + [e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) + dog (God reversed)
>
>  What + ISIS flag + dog
>
>   Wikipedia picture of [Haddaway](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddaway)

Comment: A true bork fan.